# Calculator adding decimal places

Tags: ios7, calculator

I'm working on a calculator and I'm trying to add the decimal point function so I can do math using numbers such as 3.2.  When I run the app and click on the decimal point button, the decimal is displayed on the screen (Great!).  However, when I continue adding numbers, the decimal point disappears and the numbers I'm inputting are displayed instead. For example: when I try putting in a number like 3.2, the calculator displays 32.  If you could help out that would be great.

```
- (IBAction)decimal:(id)sender {
    NSRange range = [Screen.text rangeOfString:@"."];
    if (range.location ==NSNotFound){
        Screen.text = [Screen.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for what you're doing when '2' is pressed, it seems like that's where the problem likely is.

Comment: -(IBAction)NUmber2:(id)sender{
    
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber * 10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 2;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];
}